# Fault Tolerant MST

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, trees

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ and an MST of $G$. I am wondering how many edges I need to store, to make the MST tolerant to edge failures.

If there is only one edge failure, I require at most $n-1$ edges in addition to the edges that are part of the MST. This is because for every edge on the tree, I can simply compute the best alternative edge.

But how does this change if I allow for more than one edge failure? Does linear memory ($O(n)$) still suffice for two edge failures? If yes, after how many failures will linear memory not suffice any longer?

Comment: Assuming the original graph is itself 2-edge-connected, so is fault-tolerant in that sense, you would need to extend the MST to also be 2-edge-connected, i.e. to have every vertex on a cycle. This depends strongly on what edges are available on the original graph, of course, but I think that appropriate added edges can each "back up" at least two edges on the MST.